# IntelliJ Idea + cucumber run configuration: how to exclude @tags

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, run-configuration

Good news everyone.

I don't know how to exclude several tags within my run configuration for Cucumber project.

For instance, i have three tests.

```
@debug
Scenario outline: foo 1
When step
Then step

@obsolete
Scenario outline: foo 2
When step
Then step

@stable
Scenario outline: foo 3
When step
Then step
```

I put ~@debug,~@obsolete to the textbox called «Tags Filter» of the «Run configuration» dialog window.

But there's something wrong because when I start my tests — foo 1, foo 2 and foo 3 are starting anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about IntelliJ, but on a terminal you would run:

```
cucumber --tags ~@debug --tags ~@obsolete
```

Comment: Well, that's known practice. But you can't pass --parameters in config dialog of IntelliJ Idea, only tag names. Tank you for your interest :)

Answer (score 9):

I have found the answer to this question within a comment to another stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23743258.

Basically to add several tags to IntelliJ you need to add -Dcucumber.options="--tags ~@debug --tags ~@obsolete" to the VM options in the default cucumber settings.

Answer (score 6):

For IntelliJ: Add below to the VM options by editing configuration

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @debug"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work with IDEA for with complex tag like "not @ignore". The idea just ignored it.

Answer (score 3):

Specyfing `--tags <your_tag_name>` as `Program arguments` in the `Cucumber run cofiguration` resolved the issue in my case.

Comment: That is exact answer to IDEA usage. I have indicated  --tags "not @ignore" as "Program arguments" and it run. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hence `@CucumberOptions` is obsolete with JUnit5 you have to use

```java
@ExcludeTags({ "debug", "obsolete" })
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Add tags in cucumber options**

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"}, tags = {"@Runme"}, features = "src/test/resources/urpath", glue = "your.path")
```