# How to run a single cucumber scenario in Intellij?

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, automated-tests

I have a simple problem - I want to run a single Cucumber scenario, but I can't seem to find any option/configuration for that.

I have 5-6 scenarios and I can set up configurations to run all tests, but It takes too much time, when I am correcting one scenario...

Comment: Just specify feature:start_of_line_no_of_scenario

Comment: @Bala where would one specify that?

Comment: You can specify this when running from the command line

Comment: Can you mark an answer as correct? (Santhosh seemed to have consensus)

Answer (score 16):

Tag the feature file with any name, you may add multiple tags separated with spaces.

Eg : `@acceptance` `@regression`

Now, add below options in the end of VM otions by editing configuration

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @acceptance"
```

Run the test and it will only trigger the feature files tagged with `@acceptance`

You can either set the configuration one for acceptance and one for regression or edit the configuration everytime you run it.

Comment: Where can I find VM options? Can you please explain it to me like I'm five and dumb? (I'm totally new to Java, Cucumber and Intellij :()

Answer (score 4):

Right click the scenario line in your feature file, there will be a *Run 'Scenario: My scenario'* option.

*At least in IntelliJ 2019*

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a scenario as a run argument, either though Intellij or at the command line:

As jhilan mentions - In Ruby the command looks like this:

```
cucumber path/to/file.feature:33
```

In cucumber-jvm, it looks like this:

```
-Dcucumber.options="classpath:<package-path>/<file>.feature:<line>"
```

E.g `-Dcucumber.options="classpath:com/company/my_feature.feature:6"`

To set this up in Intellij, take a look at their docs on the subject of [run configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#createExplicitly)

I know this is an old post but it's still the second highest Google result when search "executing cucumber by scenario". So I thought it deserved a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can call single Scenario by calling it line number simply
assuming your Scenario starts on line

-16 Scenario: description
       Given: etc

you can run it like this

cucumber features\test.feature:16

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old now.  If you're using cucumber-jvm nowadays, the parameter to use is now:

```
-Dcucumber.features=path/to/file.feature
```

More config options here: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#junit